# How much do you gain from minting a proof-of-stake coin on multiple wallets?

Tags: mining-profitability, proof-of-stake

Is there a theoretical gain from mining the same wallet/coins for pos on multiple computers, and if so, how much is it?

Answer (score 1):

There is no theoretical gain. It would basically be multiple computers doing the same calculations and arriving at the same result.

Look at https://github.com/ppcoin/ppcoin/blob/master/src/kernel.cpp#L290-L312. These are the things that are included in a PoS hash:

```
//   nStakeModifier: 
//       (v0.3) scrambles computation to make it very difficult to precompute
//              future proof-of-stake at the time of the coin's confirmation
//       (v0.2) nBits (deprecated): encodes all past block timestamps
//   txPrev.block.nTime: prevent nodes from guessing a good timestamp to
//                       generate transaction for future advantage
//   txPrev.offset: offset of txPrev inside block, to reduce the chance of 
//                  nodes generating coinstake at the same time
//   txPrev.nTime: reduce the chance of nodes generating coinstake at the same
//                 time
//   txPrev.vout.n: output number of txPrev, to reduce the chance of nodes
//                  generating coinstake at the same time
```

These will be the same on two different wallets, so you'll just be doing the same calculation and getting the same result on two different computers.

> **One possible theoretical gain is that blocks could be propagated from different nodes at many locations, and the blocks would spread much more quickly.**

Comment: Can you source that? Because I saw somewhere say that there's a small but real gain.

Comment: https://hashtalk.org/topic/25320/is-it-safe-to-run-my-wallet-on-multiple-computers-at-once/13

Comment: I looked at the link you sent, which wasn't super clear, but I think that person was referring to the second comment I gave, about the theoretical gain by getting blocks to propagate through the network faster. Basically it could help you win block races when blocks are solved while others are propagating.

Comment: Understood, but could you still provide a link?

Comment: Don't really have a link, there's not a lot of discussion on this, but that's just how PoS works. I'll post some more info, explaining though.